# How to get all keys/values from redis in order to insert them into SQL db?

Tags: redis

I have a lot of analytics data that I'm adding to redis.  I plan on incrementally moving the data out of redis and into my database.

I know I can use `KEYS [the_key]:*` to get all keys that match.  For example, I can do that to get the following:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS c_Track:*
1) "c_Track:6c93a5c1-77e9-4c4a-9232-bf182713a02e"
2) "c_Track:2c9d99c2-af37-4de9-ac64-b48f339e97a9"
3) "c_Track:9e7fd190-86d9-4b4a-9a70-7bf4c7768eef"
4) "c_Track:7f2d2e98-7440-4fd7-a80a-2af309ab15a4"
```

Is there a recommended way to get these values easily?  I can get the keys, but how can I get all the values as well?  I can loop through the keys to get the values, but is there some one-shot method for doing this?

Also I know I shouldn't use keys, but this is just an example.  Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also I know I shouldn't use keys

So don't. Use [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) instead.

> is there some one-shot method for doing this?

No, not as a core Redis command, but given the need this is fairly simple to achieve with a server-side Lua script. For example, assuming that your values are strings, you could do something like the following:

```
local cursor = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local pattern = ARGV[2]
local scan = redis.call('SCAN', cursor, 'MATCH', pattern)
for i, v in ipairs(scan[2]) do
  local val = redis.call('GET', v)
  scan[2][i] = { v, val }
end

return scan
```

Assuming that this script is saved under "scan.lua", you can run it as follows:

```
$ redis-cli SET foo bar
OK
$ redis-cli SET baz qaz
OK
$ redis-cli --eval scan.lua , 0 "*"
1) "0"
2) 1) 1) "baz"
      2) "qaz"
   2) 1) "foo"
      2) "bar"
```

To scan your entire keyspace, call the script with the returned cursor until it returns 0.

Notes:

1) If your keys are of different types, you should change the script accordingly (e.g. https://github.com/itamarhaber/redis-lua-scripts/blob/master/scanfetch.lua).

2) While this script goes against the common recommendation of generating key names inside a script, it is still safe to run as SCAN returns keys that are in the server's keyspace (whether single-instance or clustered).

Comment: *everyone* who has used redis has written this script in some form

Comment: I'm not sure that you're right @James - most use cases that I've seen do not require this, or any form of Lua for that matter. The beauty of Redis that it fits as-is for most needs, and Lua is regarded "advanced use". That said, I'm happy that we agree that the script delivers :-)

Comment: @James do you know any publicly available source-script that could fetch all stored key values (different data types)?

Comment: @ruhul https://github.com/itamarhaber/redis-lua-scripts/blob/master/scanfetch.lua ... but take my advice: never run a script you don't fully understand

Comment: I just need a sample how it should be done. Thanks. @haber